# Get method's parameters

Tags: actionscript-3

Is there a way to get a method's parameters from outside the method? I know that there's an "arguments" property but it's only accessable from within the method.
I'm working on a RPC system and need to store the method parameter types in a hash table for easy access later on.

Regards/Per

Answer (score 1):

Looks to the [describeType](http://www.insideria.com/2009/09/as3-reflection-using-describet.html) function it will return an XML with your function name and his arguments. It will not work for anonymous function.